# Apollo Client fetchMore get previous page for cursor based pagination

Tags: pagination, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I know for a fact that to get the next page via cursor based pagination you need to example if query is product:

```
 products(first:12, after: endCursor,)
```

Get the first n edges after your end cursor.

And to get the previous page is you need to:

```
 products(last:12, before: startCursor,)
```

Get the last n data before your start cursor.

The problem I have with apollo client is when I useQuery and fetchMore or refetch it retains the first variable from that query.

```
 const { loading, error, data, fetchMore, networkStatus } = useQuery(PRODUCTS,{
        variables: { first: 12, after: null },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    });
```

and when I get the previous page:

```
await fetchMore({
        variables: {
            before: pageInfo.startCursor,
            last:12
        }
    });
```

Then in I get a query of:

```
variables: {
        before: pageInfo.startCursor,
        last:12,
        first:12
    }
```

which returns an invalid page.

My question is how can I remove the 'first' variable if I do the previous page query.

Answer (score 1):

This was how I worked around this problem due to `fetchMore` use variables from original query.
To remove the variable that you don't want them to be included in query called by `fetchMore`, simply pass `undefined` or `null` to overwirte its original value.

For your specific case, you can do like below:

```js
fetchMore({
 variables: {
  before: pageInfo.startCursor,
  last: 12,
  first: undefined,
 }
})
```

So that the payload variable of the query is below if the value you pass is `undefined`:

```js
{
 before: <cursorValue>
 last: 12
}
```

or below if the value you pass is `null`:

```js
{
 before: <cursorValue>
 last: 12
 first: null
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've solved this long ago. We had a server problem and it does not support pagination.